# How can I add Multiple WHERE condtions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I am trying to Check and Insert record from `ITEM` to `MIBOMD`. I want to insert only if items in ItemID and partid fields in `ITEM` table exist in MIITEM table

I used the code below but I got this error message

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.

```
     USE [MITESTCO]
     GO
      INSERT INTO MIBOMD(bomItem, bomRev, bomEntry, partId, lead)
     SELECT ItemID, rev, bomEntry, partid, qty
     FROM ITEM WHERE (partid OR ItemID) IN (SELECT ItemId FROM MIITEM);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to split out the `WHERE` clause from one `OR` condition to two.

```
 USE [MITESTCO];
 GO

 INSERT INTO [MIBOMD] 
   ([bomItem], [bomRev], [bomEntry], [partId], [lead])
 SELECT [ItemID], [rev], [bomEntry], [partid], [qty]
 FROM [ITEM] 
 WHERE [partid] IN (SELECT [ItemId] FROM [MIITEM])
 OR [ItemID] IN (SELECT [ItemId] FROM [MIITEM]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is using `EXISTS`.

This will avoid using the `Sub-Query` twice

```
INSERT INTO [MIBOMD]
            ([bomItem],[bomRev],[bomEntry],[partId],[lead])
SELECT [ItemID],[rev],[bomEntry],[partid],[qty]
FROM   [ITEM] I
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   [MIITEM] M
               WHERE  M.ItemId IN ( I.partid, I.ItemID ))
```